# Python turtle isn't changing colors when i define the pen color

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Im trying to create a planet type creation thing using turtle graphics in python. I have the basic planet creation set up, but whenever I try to create a bit of shading on an arc of the planet, the pen isn't changing colors whenever I had changed it right before the shading loop. The only thing that works is by getting rid of the loop, but I don't want to clutter my code with the same statement over and over again. Here is the code for my project currently:

```
from turtle import Screen, Pen
import turtle
import random
import time
plansize = random.randrange(1, 5)


screen = Screen()
screen.title("Planet test")
pen = Pen()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(3)
pen.hideturtle()
turtle.bgcolor('black')
plasizetrue = plansize*50
screen.colormode(255)

def placreate():
    arc = 70
    randomr = int(random.randrange(0,255))
    randomg = int(random.randrange(0,255))
    randomb = int(random.randrange(0,255))
    pen.pencolor(randomr, randomg, randomb)
    counter = 0
    plasizetrue = plansize*100
    pen.right(90)
    pen.circle(plasizetrue)
    while plasizetrue > 0:
        plasizetrue -= 1
        pen.circle(plasizetrue)
        counter += 1
    randomr += 50
    randomg += 50
    randomb += 50
    if randomb > 255:
        randomb = 255
    if randomg > 255:
        randomg = 255
    if randomr > 255:
        randomr = 255
    pen.pencolor(randomr, randomg, randomb)
    while arc < 45:
        pen.circle(counter, -arc)
        pen.left(87)
        pen.forward(3)
        pen.right(87)
        arc -= 2
        pen.cirlce(counter, arc)
        pen.right(87)
        pen.forward(3)
        pen.right(87)
```

Comment: It worked for me when I put the color changing code with the drawing loop (tabbed it), could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The random colour generation is only happening once per function call since it is outside the loop. So, putting that logic inside the loop should solve the issue. For example, the random colour logic can be defined as a separate function and called in the loop.

Random colour value generator function:

```py
# Generate random integers between 0 and 255 and use them for RGB values
def rand_clr():

    rand_r = int(random.randrange(0,255))
    rand_g = int(random.randrange(0,255))
    rand_b = int(random.randrange(0,255))

    return rand_r,rand_g, rand_b
```

Planet drawing loop now becomes:

```py
    while plasizetrue > 0:
        randomr, randomg, randomb = rand_clr()
        pen.pencolor(randomr, randomg, randomb)
        plasizetrue -= 1
        pen.circle(plasizetrue)
        counter += 1
```

Output obtained:

[image: Turtle output]

Answer (score 0):

Tracked down my problem into being a wrongly placed less than sign in the

```
while arc < 45:
```

arc was set to 70 which made the loop never end up running.